# Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with int

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am trying to pass a collection of integer values to stored procedure through table

Please find below the C# code

```
 int i = lbActors.Items.Count;
            int[] actors = new int[i];
            int j = 0;

            foreach (ListItem item in lbActors.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected == true)
                {
                    actors[j] = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                    j++;
                }
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("movieAndActorType");
            dt.Columns.Add("actorId",typeof(Int32));
            int k=0;
            while(actors[k]!=0)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(actors[k]);
                k++;
            }
            try
            {
                sc.CommandText = "usp_AddMovie";
                sc.Connection = sqlCon;
                sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sc.Parameters.Add("@producerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlProducer.SelectedValue);
               sc.Parameters.Add("@actorIds", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt;
                sc.Parameters.Add("@movieName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
                sc.Parameters.Add("@yearOfRelease", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtReleaseYear.Text);
                sc.Parameters.Add("@plot", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPlot.Text;
                sc.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imgbyte;
                sqlCon.Open();
                sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" SQL error" + ex.ToString());
            }
```

In the "sql server" i am trying to enter data into below two table

```
create table tbl_movie
(
movieId int primary key IDENTITY(1,1),
producerId int foreign key references tbl_producer(producerId),
movieName varchar(30) not null unique,
yearOfRelease int not null check(yearOfRelease>1900 and yearOfRelease<=datepart(yyyy,getDate())),
plot varchar(5000) not null,
poster image 
);


   create table tbl_movieAndActor                 (
movieId int foreign key references tbl_movie(movieId),
actorId int foreign key references tbl_actor(actorId),
constraint pk_movieAndActor primary key (movieId,actorId)
);
```

created user defined type to pass the data from application to the procedure

```
     create type movieAndActorType As Table
 (
  actorId int not null
 )
```

and the stored procedure

```
create proc proc_AddMovie(@producerId int,@actorIds As movieAndActorType Readonly,@movieName varchar(50),@yearOfRelease int,@plot varchar(500),@image image)
 as
 begin

 insert into tbl_movie(producerId,movieName,yearOfRelease,plot,poster) values(@producerId,@movieName,@yearOfRelease,@plot,@image)

 insert into tbl_movieAndActor(movieId,actorId) select scope_identity(),actorId from @actorIds

 end
```

I tested the stored procedure in sql server it works fine there but when i am passing the values through my application it is throwing sql exception.

```
     "Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with int"
```

I am a naive in coding, please help me to fix this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Try change sc.Parameters.Add("@actorIds", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt; into sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actorIds", dt)

Comment: @Martheen, I tried it didn't work.

Comment: Try this for your insert into tbl_MovieAndActor table:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the reason for the error, I was using incorrect procedure name in the code. Procedure name was "Proc_addMovie" but i was using "usp_AddMpvie".After wasting a lot of time i finally noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your C# code and ensure that is it working first. Your while loop   WILL NEVER WORK. This is how to populate your table:

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("movieAndActorType");
            dt.Columns.Add("actorId", typeof(Int32));               

            for (int i = 0; i < actors.Length; i++)
            {
                var newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow["actorId"] = actors[i];
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
```

Try this for your insert into tbl_MovieAndActor table: 
        INSERT INTO tbl_movieAndActor(movieId,actorId)
        SELECT movieId = @movieId, actorId from @actorIds

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't work for me still getting the same error.

Comment: Gregg, I don't think it will work. Let me explain what i am trying to do in the procedure, I am running two insert statements one is entering data in the tbl_movie and the other is entering data in the tbl_MovieAndActor. The later one requires latest movieId as foreign key that is why i used scope_Identity() function to get the latest identity value in the scope.

Comment: I tried what you said by declaring a local variable inside my procedure then assigning scope_Identity() to it.Then i used that variable in the insert statement but it didn't work.

Comment: SqlServer needs to know the name of your type:   Change your assignment for @actorIds to:   sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@actorIds", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, Value = dt,                TypeName = "dbo.movieAndActorType" });

Comment: Can anyone please answer this question, when i am passing the stored procedure directly in sql server it works fine but when i am passing the values through application it is throwing sql exception that means i am making some mistake in the application i have tried everything i could but it didn't resolve the issue.  Can anyone please explain when this issue "Operand type clash" occurs

Answer (score 0):

It all works here with this C# code and your stored procedure:

```
     int[] actors = { 7, 8, 9 }; // Actor IDs in database                       

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("movieAndActorType");
        dt.Columns.Add("actorId", typeof(Int32));

        for(int i = 0;i <actors.Length; i++)
        {
            var dRow = dt.NewRow();
            dRow["actorId"] = actors[i];
            dt.Rows.Add(actors[i]);                
        }
        var img = new Byte[5];

        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "usp_AddMovie";
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@producerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value =   
                    Convert.ToInt32("99");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = 
                   "@actorIds", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, Value = dt, 
                    TypeName = "dbo.movieAndActorType" });
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@movieName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value 
                    = "Spectre";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@yearOfRelease", SqlDbType.Int).Value 
                    = Convert.ToInt32("1972");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@plot", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
                    "Some Plot";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image).Value =                                                             
                    img;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" SQL error" + ex.Message);
        }
```